# Could not determine storage version - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm implementing code first pattern in a separate project in my current solution. Since I did this and I initialize my connection string in `DbContext` I get this weird error:

> Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a
>   version hint is required.

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0.0.0 and the rest of my solutions projects work great as they use `EDMX` files for database access yet only my code first project throws this exception. What is it and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems problem got solved when I upgraded Entity Framework for every project using it to Entity Framework 6.1.2.

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 25):

Solved the same issue with:

Go to Solution Explorer

1. Right click on "xxx.edmx" file
2. Select "Open with" >> Editor XML Editor
3. Change ProviderManifestToken="XXXX" with 2008

Comment: It said 2012, my dev machine and the external server have both SQL Server 2012, I just tried this because well... in fact wasn't already working with value = "2012" so what you can lose... and started working! Thanks! It works!

Comment: This also worked for me. I think it might be related to targeting SQL 2008 in the deployed version while using SQL 2014 in my dev server (don't even ask why).

Comment: I'm confused. The OP seems to imply their project doesn't have an EDMX file, so how can they right click on it?

Answer (score 3):

Drop EF table `__MigrationHistory`, assuming you were just playing with migrations in test.

Answer (score 1):

Install EFTools6.1.3ForVS2012, mine got solved

Comment: Could you explain a bit more in depth what this is, and why/under which circumstances it could change anything? Does that tool have to be delivered with our product so the latter is executable?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, for some reason the app config did not have the entity framework section in configSections tag. adding it solved my issue.

[image: required app.config/web.config line]

Comment: It's always better to post text as text in questions and answers. Please change your image to text.

Comment: Could you explain why this is supposed to help, please? As far as I understand, the children of the `<configSections>` element are merely there to tell .NET's config Xml processor how to deserialize other sections in the same config file. If my config file doesn't *have* any `<entityFramework>` section to begin with, can declaring the section type in the `<configSections>` element have any effect?

Answer (score 0):

Follow following steps.

1. Update the entity framwework to latest stable version.
2. Update the edmx model.
3. Right click over file .edmx
4. Open with.. Editor XML
5. Change ProviderManifestToken="XXXX" with 2008