# Could not determine storage version error, EF 6 code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

I'm using EF code first approach in MVC and my web.config's connection string looks like-

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="XYZ-server;integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

And I'm getting following error-

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not determine storage version; a valid storage connection or a
>   version hint is required.

I also checked duplicates but none of them worked in my case-
[Duplicate question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687108/could-not-determine-storage-version-entity-framework)
[Duplicate question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38655808/could-not-determine-storage-version-a-valid-storage-connection-or-a-version-hin)

Comment: Can you try to re-installing the Entity Framework to a later version. with package manager console

PM> Install-Package EntityFramework

This will update your web.config accordingly.

Comment: Is the connection string the real connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by looking closely to the connection string, actually data source was missing, correct one is-

```
<add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=XYZ-server;integrated security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```